# Use Storyboards in Dynamic Framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, storyboard, viewcontroller

I am trying to create a dynamic framework in swift.
My Framework contains a ViewController inside a Storyboard.
I am not able to open my ViewController when a push notification comes inside my framework.
However i tried to use the below code :

```
let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "my_Framework_bundleID")
let frameworkStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "MyFrameworkStoryboard", bundle: bundle)
let viewController = frameworkStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController")
self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Doing this only executes the code inside MyViewController's `viewDidLoad` method but does not show the loads the UI.

I also tried this:

```
let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "my_Framework_bundleID")
let controller = UIViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: bundle)
present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Doing this i get the following error:

> Attempt to present UIViewController: 0x135124920 on MyFramework.anotherViewController: 0x133df1a40 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

`self.pushviewController()` and `self.show()` doesn't work as well.

I am stuck in this problem for two days.

Comment: where you call that code

Comment: If run in a viewController, you may need to run at the main thread. DispatchQueue.main.async{self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil) }

Comment: Figure out the solution. Thanks for your help guys Sh_Khan and E.Coms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to make it work

In the Appdelegate of my app where i am using my framework i passed the instance of rootviewcontroller like this:

```
test.myFunc(withRootView: (self.window?.rootViewController)!)
```

Now in my Framework i created a xib and a corresponding UIView file for it.
To navigate to this UIView file i used below code in "myFunc" function.

```
public func myFunc(withRootView rootview: UIViewController)
    let modalView = MyUIViewClass(frame: self.view.bounds)
     if rootview.presentedViewController == nil {
         rootview.view.addSubview(modalView)
     } else {
         rootview.presentedViewController?.view.addSubview(modalView)
     }
```